# Drupal 7 plugin for creating multilingual subtitle for jwplayer videos

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, jwplayer, caption, subtitle

I am using `Drupal 7`, and using [JWPLAYER](http://jwplayer.com/) for my video. Is there any plugin in `Drupal 7` which allows me to create subtitle in multiple language.

I am trying to avoid third party tools (like [dotsub](http://dotsub.com/) etc) where I need to upload my videos to their end in order to make subtitle. Is there any plugin or module in `Drupal 7` which helps me to create multi language captions for my videos in `Drupal 7` [I am using jwplayer for my videos].

Comment: Are you using a module to run JW Player in Drupal? Are you using JW Player 5 or 6?

Comment: jwplayer 6 and I am not using any module.

Comment: Okay. I am not sure of any Drupal module for creating captions files though.